# c# system stored in (DVD-RW) cannot update my textfile from other drive

Tags: c#

I have a small problem that it took me sometime to found out what should i do.
The scenario goes like this.

I created a software that I already burn to a dvd-rw and installed an autorun to it.

When my software run. It will copy all files from that dvd and will paste it to the user designated drive. But I inserted a `Flexible` variable to some sort of textfile.

After the copying is complete. The next step of my software is to find all the `Flexible` variable and change it to its final output. for example the `flexible` varialble is `<##COMPUTER_NAME>` then my software will change it to its final data. But when i do it. my system in dvd-rw says access denied.

I also tried it in my Flash Drive and it works fine. But when i tried it in DVD it says access denied.

What should i do?
P.S. my system always running as administator.

Comment: you might be trying to write to a file that is locked by the installer.

Comment: You need to check the code. If might be trying to write to the file which are on CD/DVD.

Comment: @JohnB what do you mean by lock by the installer?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya my installer is trying to update the copied file.

Comment: some process may have read/write lock on the file you are attempting to edit.

Comment: @JohnB i tried to separate the process of my software. 1dvd for copying only and the other 1dvd is for updating the value but still it say `denied`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out that my problem is the dvd-r. Because it is nature that whenever you burn a file to it, the file will become `read only` always. So when my system try to write the specific file after copying it says `denied` due to the attribute of the file.

So I made a small changes in my installer.
I added to my code the function
`Checking and changing the attribute of specific file`
before executing the second command.

That's all and it work again perfectly. `attribute` is the key.